# Feature to detect hardcoded number within the cell in spreadsheet in C#

Tags: c#, excel, formula, spreadsheet

We are working on implementing some `Excel` features in `C#` that would detect `hardcoded` number within the cell. For example:

```
=SUM(A1:B10) + 5000
```

However, there are some false positive that I'm seeing such as: 
`=SUBTOTAL(9, (A1:B10)).`Number 9  is included in the Subtotal by default already so it should not be identified as `hardcoded` number within the cell. Currently, what we can do is to add an exception to exclude certain formula such as Subtotal, `Vlookup`, `Hlookup` where there is `hardcoded` number within the formula itself by default.

**Question**: Is there a way to configure the code to detect the `hardcoded` number outside of the formula instead? For example:

`=SUBTOTAL(9,A2:A5)` --> should not be identified as number 9 is within the formula

`=SUBTOTAL(9,A2:A5) + 5000`--> should be identified as 5000 is outside of the formula

Here are some of the examples that I have:
[Excel logics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4b0vR.png)

Comment: "Is there a way to configure the code" what code? I don't see any

Comment: instead of excluding those formulas, why cant you include them and handle them appropriately

Comment: What about `=SUBTOTAL(9,A2:A5) + (5000)`  OR  `=(SUBTOTAL(9,A2:A5) + 5000)?

Comment: @Clint - What do you mean by "handle them appropriately"? - Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: For those formulas like Subtotal, Vlookup, Hlookup you process them further based on a switch case and this way you can isolate the false positives

Comment: @MKR - Good point, I would say that anything in the () of the formula itself should not be identified. So in your example, I think both should be identified because the 5000 (whether in () or not), it is still outside of the formula itself. Does that make sense?

Comment: hey @nguyehi1, I hope you understand what I tried to mean

Comment: @Clint - Can you tell more please? Would that cover any type of formula? What I'm thinking in plain English that the logic would be like: (1) Does the cell contain formula? (Y/N) (2) If Yes, separate the content of the cell to data inside the formula() and data outside of the formula() (3) data inside formula() has number --> OK, data outside formula() contains number --> Identified.

Comment: yes, I am not very familiar with excel, so I wouldn't know the edge cases but I can help if you tell me what the edge cases are

Comment: @Clint: Would this help to clarify? https://i.stack.imgur.com/4b0vR.png. Also this is the list of all Excel Functions, which are quite overwhelming (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-functions-alphabetical-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188) - Thanks for helping me with this btw.

Comment: We're essentially throwing darts here because we can't see the spreadsheet you're working with - whether or not the formula use-cases are formatted consistently, etc. Using regex, you can remove/omit the formula data, isolate the last number in the string, etc. We just don't know how to provide the answer without more information.

Comment: @nguyehi1, Ill take a look at this, when I have some time, in the mean while I would recommend you  revisit the doc you created and https://i.stack.imgur.com/4b0vR.png and find a pattern. Write some code and post what you've tried, I do not want to write things from scratch

Comment: @Clint - we have the code that currently exclude Vlookup and Hlookup formula using formulaStack.Peek().Value.ToUpper() == "VLOOKUP" || formulaStack.Peek().Value.ToUpper() == "HLOOKUP" along with some other rules like division of 100..etc.. I'm not allowed to share the full code so apologies for that. I think it's possible to parse the formula and set a rule to identify the number inside and outside of the formula but if the formula/function type varies (name, format such as Subtotal(), Hlookup(), Index()...etc) - idk if regex would be the solution. Thoughts?